# Pandas: How to efficiently diff() after a groupby() operation?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I do have a large dataset (around 8 million rows x 25 columns) in Pandas and I am struggling to use the diff() function in a performant manner on a subset of the data.

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
                   prec   type
location_id hours             
135         78     12.0      A
            79     14.0      A
            80     14.3      A
            81     15.0      A
            82     15.0      A
            83     15.0      A
            84     15.5      A
```

- I have a multi-index on [location_id, hours]. I have around 60k locations and 140 hours for each location (making up the 8 million rows).
- The rest of the data is numeric (float) or categorical. I have only included 2 columns here, normally there are around 20 columns.
- What I am willing to do is to apply the diff() function for each location on the `prec` column. The original dataset piles up the `prec` numbers; by applying diff() I will get the appropriate `prec` value for each hour.
- With these in mind, I have implemented the following algorithm in Pandas:

```
# Filter the data first
df_filtered = df_data[df_data.type == "A"] # only work on locations with 'A' type
df_filtered = df_filtered.query('hours > 0 & hours <= 120') # only work on certain hours

# Apply the diff()
for location_id, data_of_location in df_filtered.groupby(level="location_id"):
    df_data.loc[data_of_location.index, "prec"] = data_of_location.prec.diff().replace(np.nan, 0.0)
del df_filtered
```

- This works really well functionally, however the performance and the memory consumption is horrible. It is taking around 30 minutes on my dataset and that is currently not acceptable. The existence of the for loop is an indicator that this could be handled better.
- Is there a better/faster way to implement this?
- Also, the overall memory consumption of the Python script is sky-rocketing during this operation; it grows around 300%! The memory consumed by the main `df_data` data frame doesn't change but the overall process memory consumption rises.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511144/pandas-diff-seriesgroupby-is-relatively-slow

Comment: I'm not sure but with index alignment, you could try without loop `df_data.loc[:, 'prec'] = df_filtered.groupby(level="location_id")['prec'].diff().fillna(0)` and it might be faster?

Comment: @Ben.T That looked promising and I have given it a shot but it set all the values of the `prec` column to NaN. The indexing does look off there.

Comment: `df[_data['prec'] = df_filtered.groupby('location_id')['prec'].diff()` should work as expected.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have tried that and it also yielded all `NaN` values.

Comment: It might indicate that your data is not indexed by `location_id` or the filtered data is empty.

Comment: Could you add the result of `df_data[['prec','type']].head().to_dict()` to your question?

Comment: @QuangHoang: I think you almost had it right, the problem with your proposal is that it just `NaN`s the rest of the data that is not covered by the diff(); the data of type `B` gets the `NaN` values. You can take a look at my answer below for details.

Comment: @Ben.T: Same as my comment above, you also pointed me to the right direction. You can take a look at my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

With the input from @Quang Hoang and @Ben. T, I figured out a solution that is pretty fast but still consumes a lot of memory.

```
# Filter the data first
df_filtered = df_data[df_data.type == "A"] # only work on locations with 'A' type
df_filtered = df_filtered.query('hours > 0 & hours <= 120') # only work on certain hours

# Apply the diff()
df_diffed = df_data.groupby(level="location_id").prec.diff().replace(np.nan, 0.0)
df_data[df_diffed.index, "prec"] = df_diffed
del df_diffed
del df_filtered
```

I am guessing 2 things can be done to improve memory usage:

- `df_filtered` seems like a copy of the data; that should increase the memory a lot.
- `df_diffed` is also a copy.

The memory usage is very intensive while computing these two variables. I am not sure if there is any `in-place` way to execute such operations.